# React select - change the way selected values are shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using [react select](https://react-select.com/home) control in my ReactJs based application. I am using this as a multi-select control. But once the user selects more than 1 value, instead of showing all the selected values, I want to show the first selected value + N. So if two values are selected, I want to say 'XYZ' + 1. If only one value is selected I will say 'XYZ'. here is a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-silence-e6eht)

Comment: How do you determine `+ N`? Is it something like if a user selects option 1, then also selects option 3, that you display options 1, 2, and 3? or if they also select option 3 you just display option 1 and 2? You're expected result could use a bit more detail.

Comment: React-select will only display the labels that are available in the array that you provide.

Comment: @DrewReese:If user select `Option 1`, since this the only item selected, we will show Option 1 as the selected value. now if user selects `Option 3`, we will show `Option 1 + 1` as we have two selected items in control. if user selects `Option 6`, we will show `Option 1 + 2` as we have three selected items in control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override ValueContainer like below. working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-satoshi-wvhks?file=/src/MySelectComponent.js)

```
const ValueContainer = props => {
  let length = props.getValue().length;

  return (
    <components.ValueContainer {...props}>
      {length > 1 ? (
        <>
          {props.children[0][0]}
          {!props.selectProps.menuIsOpen && `${length - 1} Items`}
          {React.cloneElement(props.children[1])}
        </>
      ) : (
        <>{props.children}</>
      )}
    </components.ValueContainer>
  );
};
```

In Select you need to override

```
<Select
 components={{ValueContainer}}
 hideSelectedOptions={false}
 ...
/>
```

Comment: Upvoting as solution works. But now, how do we remove some of the selected values?

Comment: You can avoid hiding selected values, so that selected values are available in dropdown for unselecting. 
```
<Select
components={{ValueContainer}}
hideSelectedOptions={false}
...
/>
```
Updated sandbox also.

Comment: Can you please explain what is happening inside `ValueContainer`